# Restructure List<MyType> to List<List<MyType>>

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have an ArrayList which looks like this:

```
final List<MyType> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

MyType looks like this:

```
public class MyType {
   ...
   private DateTime startTime;
   private DateTime endTime;
   private DateTime dateOfContainer; // I use @JSONSerializer here to only serialize date
   ....
}
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
 {
...
"endTime": "16:00",
"startTime": "13:00",
"dateOfContainer": "27.11.2015"
},
{
...
"endTime": "12:00",
"startTime": "08:00",
"dateOfContainer": "27.11.2015"
},
{
... 
"endTime": "16:00",
"startTime": "13:00",
"dateOfContainer": "25.11.2015"
}, 
{
...
"endTime": "19:00",
"startTime": "18:00",
"dateOfContainer": "21.11.2015"
},
...
```

Now I would a list like this:

```
List<List<MyType>>
```

where MyType's with the same **dateOfContainer** are together, e.g. the first two.

Is there a simple way with Java-8 to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myList.stream().collect (Collectors.groupingBy(MyType::getDateOfContainer))` will give you a `Map<DateTime,List<MyType>>` where your objects are grouped by the date property.

To get a `List<List<MyType>>` from this `Map`, you can create an `ArrayList` and initialize it with the values of that `Map` :

```
List<List<MyType>> list = new ArrayList<> (
    myList.stream().collect (Collectors.groupingBy(MyType::getDateOfContainer)).values());
```

Note that in order for `groupingBy` to function as expected, the `DateTime` class must override `equals`. I'm not sure if that's the case here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this approach, It works great, I would have one further question concerning this issue. Is it possible to get a **ordered List** of **List<MyType>** so that the latest List<MyType> comes first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3318489,use instead `Collectors.groupingBy(MyType::getDateOfContainer, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList())`